# what type of data receive as parameters the method predict of a LinearRegression instance from sklearn?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I am doing an example of **Linear Regression** with **sciki-learn** but i am confuse about the **predict** method;

In [Scikit-Learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) you will see this;

```
my_Linear_Model.predict(self, X)
```

**Parameters:**

**X** : array_like or sparse matrix, shape (n_samples, n_features)
Samples.

Note: array_like does not give me enough information of what type of data a predict method could receive. Remember that with Pandas we deal with Serie and DataFrame object.

I want to know the different types of array the predict method could receive.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: array_like does not give me enough information of what type of data a predict method could receive. Remember that with Pandas we deal with Serie and DataFrame object.

For linear regression in scikit-learn you need to use numeric types of your columns (int oder float), the other types are not able to read.

If you have a dataframe df:

```
df
A  B  C target
1  1  1 1
2  3  -1 10
```

you will select your array X, directly as columns from your dataframe:

```
X = df[['A', 'B', 'C']]
```

your target variable y, you will also select from your dataframe:

```
y = df[['target']]
```